# difference of two different allocations of subclass

Tags: java, allocation

Animal is the parent class of Cat class.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Animal myCat1 = new Cat;  //Allocation 1
Cat myCat2 = new Cat;    //Allocation 2
}
```

What is the diffrerence of two allocation??Each is true ,isn't it?

Comment: There is a difference ! You cannot invoke Cat methods on myCat1 reference because it is declare a Animal, so only Animal methods are available. For myCat2, both Animal and Cat methods can be called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of these are valid. You need `()`. Apart from that:

- the first referes to the instance by its superclass
- the second refers to it by its class

You can refer to any object by any of its superclasses, up to `Object`. This is polymorphism.

Answer (score 5):

```
Animal myCat1 = new Cat();
```

This is called `polymorphism` where the super class reference can hold a sub-class object.

Read Java tutorial: [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Comment: I read the page you talked about very carefully and grasp the codes. But what is the relation of the codes with the polymorphism ??I didn't understand what is the polymorphism ? At the end of the page it is said that:The Java virtual machine (JVM) calls the appropriate method for the object that is referred to in each variable. It does not call the method that is defined by the variable's type. This behavior is referred to as virtual method invocation and demonstrates an aspect of the important polymorphism features in the Java. I didn't understand what does it mean ?? Can you please clarify??

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:
  There is no difference - in both cases 'new Cat ()' allocates an instance of the Cat class.
  Both are true - myCat1 is an animal (in fact, a Cat) and myCat2 is a Cat.